# Max pixel issue exporting NDVI map (Landsat 5 and 8) from GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, ndvi, landsat, extract

I want to export an NDVI map for the Quebec province, Canada, from GEE so that I can select my sampling locations after importing the map on QGIS. But I get this error:

> Error: Export too large: specified 8030040147504 pixels (max: 1000). Specify higher maxPixels value if you intend to export a large area. (Error code: 3)

I tried to look at videos on YouTube and read answers to similar questions on StackExchange, but the examples are for one type of Landsat and not for a mix of two Landsats. I will really appreciate it if someone can help me with modifying the code.

Here is the link to the script:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/0ca4247b9b45abbece8491289b65a878

Here is the code:

```js
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_L2")
var S9 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2")


// to add Geometry
var addNDVI = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image
    .clip(geometry)
    .normalizedDifference(['SR_B4', 'SR_B3'])
    .rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
};

var addNDVI2 = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image
    .normalizedDifference(['SR_B5', 'SR_B4'])
    .rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
};
// Filter par date et calculer la mosaique
var withNDVI = S2.map(addNDVI).filterDate('1988-06-15', '2012-08-30').qualityMosaic('NDVI').select('NDVI');
var withNDVI_2 = S9.map(addNDVI2).filterDate('2013-06-15', '2022-08-30').qualityMosaic('NDVI').select('NDVI');

var NDVI_diff = withNDVI_2.subtract(withNDVI)

var ndviParams = {min: -1.5, max: 1.5, palette: ['black', 'white', 'green']};

//visualiser sur la carte
Map.centerObject(geometry)
Map.addLayer(NDVI_diff, ndviParams, 'NDVI image');

// Exporter l'image vers Drive.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: withNDVI,
  description: 'NDVI-1985',
  scale: 10,
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
  formatOptions: {
    cloudOptimized: true
  },
  maxPixels: 1e13
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to export the whole world in 10m scale:

```
print(NDVI_diff.geometry())
```

> Polygon, 5 vertices type:  Polygon coordinates:  List (1 element) 0:
> List (5 elements) 0:  [-180,-90] 1:  [180,-90] 2:  [180,90] 3:
> [-180,90] 4:  [-180,-90]

You can explicitly specify the `region` when exporting.

```
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: withNDVI,
  description: 'NDVI-1985',
  region: geometry,
  scale: 10,
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
  formatOptions: {
    cloudOptimized: true
  },
  maxPixels: 1e13
})
```

Also, avoid `clip()` until the last step of your processing, as it's quite costly. Here, you're doing it when mapping over the collection. Instead, clip the image you add to the map.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually, I am almost an amateur in GEE, and I am not familiar with the scale and max pixel. I want to export the map for the Quebec province, Canada, as the main part of my Ph.D. project. I tried to specify the geometry by drawing a rectangle as you can see in the link. But I am not sure if I did it correctly. Can you please help me more so that we can export the image for only Quebec? Thanks a lot

Comment: Just add `region` when exporting - i've got the code snippet in my answer. That will limit the export to only your geometry. The `scale` is the resolution in meters per pixel and `maxPixels` is the maximum number of pixels you want to allow in your export.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I added the region, but still I get the same error. https://code.earthengine.google.com/87bff44626a48eee10dedd40612c308a

Comment: I don't see any errors when running your script. Are you sure it's the same error, not something else, like running out of Google Drive space?

Comment: Thank you so much, Daniel. I have just tried it once again and I noticed that it works. Thanks a million